# Phing: Group targets which are listed by "phing -l"

Tags: php, phing

Is there a possibility to separate the targets in the build.xml file which are listed by the following command?:

phing -l

Because currently I see all targets under the "Main targets" headline. I would like to have several groups. Like "Database", "PHP" etc. Is this possible? I have not found anything like this by the documentation and Google and of course the search function at Stackoverflow.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for now. There is not attributes for [Target](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html#Target) for this purpose.

I will explain you my workaround:

I have a folder bin/targets (avoid to use bin/phing if you are using composer to handle phing dependencies) with several xml files:

```
bin/targets/
├── db
│   ├── default.xml
│   └── one_database.xml
├── geonames.xml
├── jmeter.xml
├── qcode.xml
├── skel.xml
├── symfony.xml
└── test.xml
```

Each one has several targets, and all of them are prefixed with the "namespace". In example, target with name **db.one_database.deploy** is in this file **./bin/targets/db/one_database.xml**,

At the end of my build.xml file I have these instructions

```
<import file="bin/targets/skel.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="vendor/corretgecom/phing-base64/bin/phing/qgpl/corretgecom.qgpl.base64.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/symfony.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/test.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/qcode.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/jmeter.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/db/default.xml" optional="false" />
<import file="bin/targets/db/one_database.xml" optional="false" />
```

When you execute *bin/phing -l* targets are not in separated groups but namespaced and sorted by name :)